# Why my quotation is disappearing as soon I type something inside it?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, quotations

When I put two quotations, and as soon I typed something inside it, one of the quotations gets deleted. For example, If I typed first "" then after I typed something inside it, then the result will be: `"house`.

The last quotation automatically gets deleted. Why? Although there was a problem of quotations not appearing until I pressed two times called as dead keys and I fixed it by changing keyboard input language. But the disappearing of one quotation when I typed something is still a problem.

Can anyone please tell me?
I am really having trouble during programming. 
Especially this happens in Eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean that you have the Eclipse preference for automatically adding the quote characters, and it is disappearing, or that you don't have that setting and you are manually typing a quote character twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have “Overtype” enabled. Click the “Insert” or “INS” key on your keyboard once, then it should be fixed!

If this fixed your problem, please click the check mark on the left side of this response.

Comment: If this is correct - then this question is nothing to do with programming and should be deleted.

Comment: @achAmháin Questions about programming tools are on-topic. From the Help center: "_if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is 
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_"

Comment: @Teemu not sure how having the insert button on a keyboard pressed qualifies as *unique to software development*...

Comment: @achAmháin The described behavior is unique to Eclipse (a _software developing tool_). Try to change the Insert Mode in another code editor, it won't mess your code ...

Comment: @achAmháin since it is a problem someone is facing in a specific use case, it is acceptable here

Comment: Pressing Insert Key actually works for me. But how??
How just the insert key solves the problem??

Comment: @sophin It disables overtype.